# Site listing by location

Tags: domain-name-system

Apologies if this is the incorrect tag for this question.

Is there a publicly available list to discover all sites that are registered by country? For example all internet sites that are registered/created in Ireland ?

Googling 'list of Internet sites by country' does not offer such information.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. This information isn't open to the public.
You can however download parts of these lists from the whois database but this comes at a price:
https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whois-database-download.php

Depending on your needs you could also inquire about this information directly at the registries but unless you have a very good reason for it you won't get this information (we're talking about millions upon millions of records).